# Django model for users with own data

Tags: database, django, model

I'm going to build an app, where each user has access to only own data.
Each user should be able to add/edit/delete own data. Columns in table should looks like this:

```
"Product name" "Date of purchase" "Price" "Warranty" "Comments"
```

I assume size of app for up to 100 users and up to 1000 items per user. 
Now, I'm wondering what kind of model should I build. 
Should I create one table and add "User" column, and later filter this table by User, or should I create 3 tables: "Users", "Items" and "Users to items relations"?
What is your opinion? Which solution will be the best for such app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create 2 tables in one models.py file. One table should have user data, the other one should contain item data, with a foreign key field relating it to a single user.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have *2* models, `Users` and `Items` with a ForeignKey to the `User` model. This will result in *2* tables. Then you can add the logic to only allow a user to modify/delete `Item` objects that belong to them.

Another option is to use something like [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian).

Comment: Doing it this way, the many to many field wouldn't even be necessary, so long as the item contains a foreign key field tying it to a user.

Comment: Ah, yes. I was thinking along the lines of permissions. So multiple users could have write permission to a single item.

Comment: Do I understand corectly, that I should have 2 tables. One "auth_user", provided by Django and one mentioned above with User field witch will point to "auth_user" for each line? Right?

Comment: Yes, but if you have a custom `User` model the table will not be called `auth_user`. [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example).